# Sails-OrientDB LinkedList Type

Tags: node.js, sails.js, orientdb, sails-orientdb

Im using Sails-Orientdb and looking to have LinkedList OrientDB type instead of an EmbeddedList

I am defining it like below

```
experience: {
    type: 'array'
}
```

Is there any way to make the array type become LinkedList?

Comment: this is why I don't use sails-orientdb

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: No the adapter doesnt seem to be maintained anymore